# Login by email instead of username

Tags: 7, users

I can't find if it is possible or not to change the log in system by using the couple (email, password) instead of (username, password).

I think people never remember their usernames when not available as they wanted and so had to add a number at the end of it ...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Both the [Login Toboggan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) and [Email Registration](http://drupal.org/project/email_registration) modules allow your users to use their email when logging in.

Comment: Mind you that LoginToboggan has a different (not to say *problematic*) approach of administrator approvals: https://www.drupal.org/node/1069414

Answer (score 0):

The developer has moved a module that meets your need from the sandbox to the project page:
https://www.drupal.org/project/login_email

The module exists as 7.x-1.x-dev  It works as is...looks like a bit of assistance can turn this into an official release.

Answer (score 0):

In order to allow both username and email:
first add validator

```
function YOURMODULE_form_user_login_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['#validate'][1] = 'YOURMODULE_form_user_login_replace_email_validate';
    $form['#validate'][2] = 'user_login_authenticate_validate';
    $form['#validate'][3] = 'user_login_final_validate';
}
```

then check if looks like email address (contains @, letters before and after @ and at least 1 '.' after @).
If it is, than replace email by username:

```
function YOURMODULE_form_user_login_replace_email_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {

    $name = $form_state['values']['name'];
    if (strpos($name, '@')) {
        $mailParts = explode('@', $name);
        if ((int)count($mailParts) === 2) {
            $extParts = explode('.', $mailParts[1]);
            if (count($extParts) > 1) {
                $query = db_select('users', 'u');
                $query->distinct();
                $query->fields('u', ['uid']);
                $query->fields('u', ['name']);
                $query->fields('u', ['mail']);
                $query->condition('u.mail', $name, '=');
                $result = $query->execute()->fetchAllAssoc('name');

                if (!empty($result)) {
                    $name = array_keys($result)[0];
                    $form_state['values']['name'] = $name;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I had a specific situation when I had to add email-based authentification to working site with a lot of users leaving the "old" authentification working, and I did it in such a way.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to let a user login with their email address in Drupal 7:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {

  // On the user login form...
  if ($form_id == 'user_login') {
  
    // OPTIONAL: Change the title on the user name input.
    $form['name']['#title'] = t('E-mail address');

    // OPTIONAL: Clear the descriptions on the user name and pass inputs.
    $form['name']['#description'] = '';
    $form['pass']['#description'] = '';

    // Prepend a custom validation handler.
    array_unshift($form['#validate'], 'MY_MODULE_user_login_form_validate');

  }

}

/**
 * A custom validation handler for the user login form.
 */
function MY_MODULE_user_login_form_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {

  // If they provided a valid email address for the user name...
  $name = $form_state['values']['name'];
  if (valid_email_address($name)) {
  
    // If an account exists for the email address...
    $account = user_load_by_mail($name);
    if ($account) {
    
      // Set the account's user name onto the form state.
      form_set_value($form['name'], $account->name, $form_state);

    }

  }

}
```